# can URLs be used as the xsl reference within XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt

A quick question regarding referencing XSL stylesheets from XML...

Up until now I have always referenced a stylesheet using a UNC, e.g.:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="\\test\...
```

Now I am looking at referencing the XSL using a URL, e.g.:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://mysite.com/xsltest.xsl
```

however this is failing with an "access is denied error processing the
resource" (i.e. the XSL)

So just to confirm -- can URLs be used as the XSL reference within XML?

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using? Is this in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes. You should be able just open that XML in any modern browser and see XSL being applied.

But in general it depends how do you process your XML - for example you might be able to open that URL in your browser but XML processor won't be able to because of proxy or firewall for example.

Answer (score 0):

As href pseudoattribute is an IRI, which is an internationalized URI  - it should work.

You shouldn't put UNC in href pseudoattribute (and in any other place expecting URI/IRI/URL) as it's not even a valid URI.

edit
examples:

1. URL as href attribute:

   ```
   <?xml-stylesheet type="application/xsl" href="http://www.domain.com/sheet.xsl" ?>.
   ```
2. URI (that's not URL) as href attribute:

   ```
   <?xml-stylesheet type="application/xsl" href="urn:isbn:0451450523" ?>
   ```

   In this case it's syntactically correct but semantically it doesn't make sense (stylesheet is referenced by isbn ;)) Also, there are URI's which look like they're URL (even with http:// in the beginning) but don't point to anything. That's legal. URI is JUST an identifier, not necesarily a location.
3. IRI (that's not URI) as href attribute

   ```
   <?xml-stylesheet type="application/xsl" href="urn:country:españa" ?>
   ```

   doesn't make much sense either, but it's just an example.
   IRI is a superset of URI with support for unicode characters (ñ in the example).

**Incorrect use of UNC where IRI is expected**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="application/xsl" href="\\youserver\resource" ?>
```

This IS illegal. UNC (uniform naming convention ) string IS NOT an IRI (and therefore not an URI nor URL). 
xml-stylesheet definition permits only IRI as values of href attribute, therefore putting UNC string there is incorrect and you simply got lucky it worked. It probably wouldn't work if you tried to open your xml in any non-windows OS.

Comment: <?xml-stylesheet type="application/xsl" href="test.xsl" IRI="http://foo.com/"?>
is this what you have been talking about

Comment: @Amit No. href attribute is an IRI (internationalized resource identifier), which is a superset of URI (which in turn are superset of URL). So any url should do there, including the one you tried. The href="\\test\." is another story as it's not a valid IRI/URI/URL and will probably work only on windows. You DON'T want your xml to be windows only.

Comment: can you quote an example of the same. I searched around but couldn't find one. Really appreciate your help !